# Android - ClassNotFoundException (TwitterAPI)

Tags: java, android, twitter, android-studio

Okay so I've been messing around with the Twitter API, and all of a sudden I've started to get the ClassNotFoundException error code when I try and enter the Activity which has my login box to sign into Twitter.

Here's the error code.

```
2398-2398/josh.com.twitterapi E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'josh.com.twitterapi.LoginActivity', referenced from method josh.com.twitterapi.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem
07-05 02:19:30.138    2398-2398/josh.com.twitterapi E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: josh.com.twitterapi.LoginActivity
        at josh.com.twitterapi.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:204)
        at josh.com.twitterapi.NavigationDrawerFragment.access$000(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:32)
        at josh.com.twitterapi.NavigationDrawerFragment$1.onItemClick(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:99)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3973)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 02:21:03.973    3223-3223/josh.com.twitterapi E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'josh.com.twitterapi.LoginActivity', referenced from method josh.com.twitterapi.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem
```

This is my LoginActivity.java.

```
        package josh.com.socialme;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;

    import com.codepath.oauth.OAuthLoginActivity;


    public class LoginActivity extends OAuthLoginActivity<TwitterClient> {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        }

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // OAuth authenticated successfully, launch primary authenticated activity
        // i.e Display application "homepage"
        @Override
        public void onLoginSuccess() {
            // Intent i = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
            // startActivity(i);
        }

        // OAuth authentication flow failed, handle the error
        // i.e Display an error dialog or toast
        @Override
        public void onLoginFailure(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Click handler method for the button used to start OAuth flow
        // Uses the client to initiate OAuth authorization
        // This should be tied to a button used to login
        public void loginToRest(View view) {
            getClient().connect();
        }

    }

This is my AndroidManifest.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="josh.com.socialme" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Hub"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Feed"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_feed" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my method I use to get to the activity.

```
    private void selectItem(int position) {
    // Handle Navigation Options
    Intent intent;
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Feed.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            break;


    }

}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me towards the right direction.

Kind regards,
Josh

(AndroidManifest.xml as requested)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="josh.com.socialme" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Hub"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Feed"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_feed" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_login_activity" >

            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The NoClassDefFoundError is saying that it can't locate `josh.com.twitterapi.LoginActivity`, but in your LoginActivity class, you define its package as `josh.com.socialme`.  You should post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Ah that's my fault, the LoginActivity is actually inside of com.josh.socialme. Not com.josh.twitterapi. I have no idea why the 'socialme' got replaced with 'twitterapi'. Anyways, here's my AndroidManifest file.